# Prevent zoom changes in Windows when switching users

Tags: windows-10, zoom, multiple-users, fast-user-switching, user-switching

Whenever I switch between two users in my Windows 10, it keeps readjusting the zoom level. However both users have the same 150% zoom level set. I am not sure why Windows goes back to 100% for a short period of time.

I click Windows+L then I sign in with a fingerprint. After that for a short period of time I see everything on zoom level 100%, then it starts flickering for a few seconds and eventually goes back to 150%.

I tried copying user settings to the Welcome screen but it's didn't fix the problem.

I would appreciate any help!